# Oracle Apex page can´t fetch data after navigating to another and returning

Tags: forms, oracle-apex, ora-01403

So i have a form based on one of my table, in wich the id is generated by a function in the database, the username is get from the user in session using the variable `:APP_USER` and the date has a default value of `to_char(sysdate)`. But the problem is that if I open the page the first time it does work without any error, when I change pages and return to the form I get the error

```
ORA-01403: no data found
 Error Unable to fetch row.
```

And I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the standard fetching process you can check to see which column it uses to fetch a unique row and the item it will use the value from to do this.
If you get the 1403 error then this probably means you are trying to perform a fetch with the value of this page item set to a value which does not exist in the database.
Are you performing a computation on this item? Run plsql code on it? Change it anywhere?
When you get this error, then you can check the session state of the item by clicking "Session" on the developer toolbar. This will show you the session state values of the items, and thus you can see the value of the PK item on which the fetch will operate. If there is an id in there, you can verify whether this value is correct or not.